# Google Drive SDK authorization

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have been trying to follow the Quickstart: Run a Drive app in JavaScript sample in order to use Google Drive API and SDK. I went through the authentication and set up the `Client ID` and `API key` etc. I had assumed that the token can be created without the user being logged in to a Google Account, since the client has the `Client ID` that is connected to a Project on Google Developer Console. Am I missing something here?

Can a user use the JavaScript based Google Drive app without logging in to a Google Account?

Answer (score 0):

no. From your question, it sounds like you've interpreted client ID as referring to the user. Client ID refers to the app. So separately, Google needs to confirm the user has given his permission, and that requires authentication, ie login

Comment: So here's my scenario - I need the application to connect to a Google Account (Which is basically the application account) and be able to make changes to the drive like making copies of files, deleting files. The user is able to make changes only though the Web based App and will not be given full access to the account. So doesn't need to have the login info for he account.

Comment: Easy peasy. You've just described a Service Account https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount. You'll need to unlearn a lot of the Quick Start stuff as that's oriented to authorizing a user account.

Comment: Your question talks about JavaScript. Note that Service Accounts are implemented server side. Thus any JavaScript will need to communicate with a server app, and NOT directly to Drive.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to Service Accounts. I'll delve into those and see if I can make things work.